# Sidebar not getting closed or opened on first click when I open any menu inside sidebar

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Bootstrap 4. I am toggling the sidebar to open and close which is working okay. But when I open any of the menus inside the sidebar and click the close icon, then it does not close on the first click, however, it gets closed on the second click.
Also sometimes, when I open the sidebar and click outside twice or thrice out of the sidebar, then it does not open on the first click and I have to click twice or thrice on the hamburger button to make it open.
I am unable to find out its solution. There is perhaps some problem with the jQuery code. If anyone knows what the problem is, then please let me know the trick. Thank You in Advance.

This is the HTML code =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <title>Sidebar</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="dashboard-main-body">
        <nav class="dashboard-nav">
            <div class="dashboard-nav-wrapper">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                  <span>LOGO</span>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div class="dashboard-user dropdown">
                
                  <div class="mobile-navbar-toggler" id="mobileToggler">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                  </div>
              </div>   
        </nav>
        <div class="dashboard-inner-body">
            <aside class="dashboard-sidebar">
                <ul class="nav flex-column mt-3">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown sidebar-dropdown">
                      <a role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 1</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu sidebar-dropdown-menu bg-dark" style="position: relative;">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown sidebar-dropdown">
                      <a role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu sidebar-dropdown-menu bg-dark" style="position: relative;">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown sidebar-dropdown">
                      <a role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 3</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu sidebar-dropdown-menu bg-dark" style="position: relative;">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </aside>
            <div class="dashboard-right-section">
                <div class="your-referral-header-box">
                    <h2 class="your-referral-heading justify-content-center">Dashboard</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the jquery Code =>

```
<script>
      $(function(){
        var mobileToggler = $("#mobileToggler");
        var dashboardSidebar = $(".dashboard-sidebar");

          $(window).on("mouseup", function(){
            if($(event.target).closest(mobileToggler[0].length == 1)){
              mobileToggler.on("click touch", function(){
                $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times")
                dashboardSidebar.toggleClass("go-left");
                return;
              });
            }

            if(!$(event.target).closest(dashboardSidebar).length){
              if(dashboardSidebar.hasClass("go-left")){
                dashboardSidebar.toggleClass("go-left");
                mobileToggler.find("i").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
                return;
              }
            }
          });
      });
    </script>
```

This is the CSS code =>

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.referral-statistics-div {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto 3rem;
}
.dashboard-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
.dashboard-nav .dashboard-nav-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.dashboard-nav .dashboard-user .mobile-navbar-toggler {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.dashboard-inner-body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EBF1FE;
  position: relative;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-sidebar {
  background-color: #070B14;
  width: 200px;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-sidebar .nav .nav-item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-sidebar .nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-sidebar .nav .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #85A3E0;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-sidebar .nav .active .nav-link {
  background-color: #85A3E0;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-right-section {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-right-section .your-referral-header-box {
  background-color: #73818F;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
}
.dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-right-section .your-referral-header-box .your-referral-heading {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.85rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-dropdown .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
.sidebar-dropdown .dropdown-toggle::before {
  content: "";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
.sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative !important;
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
          transform: none !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-dropdown-menu .dropdown-item .nav-link {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem 0.5rem 3.4rem;
}

.sidebar-dropdown.show .dropdown-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-expanded {
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-column-mob {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
  .dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .dashboard-inner-body .go-left {
    left: 0;
  }
  .dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-right-section {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-right-section .your-referral-header-box {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
  .dashboard-inner-body .dashboard-right-section .your-referral-header-box .your-referral-heading {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }

  .dashboard-nav .dashboard-user .mobile-navbar-toggler {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}
```